# How to cross-compile Perl modules (here: Device::SerialPort) for Synology DS218+?

Tags: perl, cross-compiling, perl-module, synology

I am trying to build a Perl module (Device::SerialPort) for my Synology Diskstation DS218+ which runs on an Intel Celeron J3355 (Apollolake) processor. I managed to build even more complex packages for the Synology such as "make" via the spksrc Synology Toolchain in a Docker image running on the same machine, but have failed to do so with Perl modules.
I have tried to just build them for the same Perl version that the DS218+ runs (currently 5.24.0) using perlbrew and copy the resulting files over, but the best I could get is an error such as "undefined symbol: PL_stack_sp at /usr/local/share/perl5/core_perl/XSLoader.pm".

EDIT: Here are the outputs of perl -V on the target system:

```
[user@DS218 ~]$ perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 24 subversion 0) configuration:
Derived from: fa04148f1272140cc97a02f4fca347a6540dc6b5
Platform:
osname=linux, osvers=current, archname=x86_64-linux
Compiler:
Linker and Libraries:
Dynamic Linking:
Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
Compile-time options: HAS_TIMES MULTIPLICITY PERLIO_LAYERS
                    PERL_COPY_ON_WRITE PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                    PERL_HASH_FUNC_ONE_AT_A_TIME_HARD
                    PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_MALLOC_WRAP
                    PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV USE_64_BIT_ALL USE_ITHREADS
                    USE_LARGE_FILES USE_LOCALE USE_LOCALE_COLLATE
                    USE_LOCALE_CTYPE USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC USE_LOCALE_TIME
                    USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF USE_REENTRANT_API
Locally applied patches:
uncommitted-changes
Built under linux
Compiled at Jan 21 2019 19:42:02
@INC:
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl
/usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl
/usr/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/local/share/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/local/lib/perl5/core_perl
/usr/local/share/perl5/core_perl
```

I know I could install a third party package manager such as IPGK, but I don't want the overhead (plus like to learn ;) ). I'd settle for a pre-compiled binary that actually works on the DS218+ if someone could point me to it.

(And for those not knowing the DS218+ well enough: CPAN is not an option because the Synologies are not shipped with a C compiler, and cross-compiling gcc with the Toolchain is equally frustrating).

Thanks a lot in advance for any pointers!

Comment: What's the CPU architecture and operating system of the target system?

Comment: @daxim: It' an Intel Celeron J3355 (64 bit Intel) running a Linux-based OS called DSO (DiskStation Operating System).

Answer (score 0):

To improve your replicated environment, run `perl -V` on the target system to see how it was configured. Relevant items, possibly more:

```
cccdlflags
ccdlflags
ccflags
ccversion
config_args
gccversion
gnulibc_version
lddlflags
libc
libs
```

Comment: Sorry, should have thought about this myself, added it in the original post due to size limitations here.

Comment: This was pushing me to the right direction! Although I installed Perl using "--both threads", perl -V was not showing USE_ITHREADS in the compile-time options. Only by explicitly installing it with `perlbrew install 5.24.0 -Dusethreads` it appeared. I have then copied both the resulting auto and Device folders to my home folder of the DS218 and now another strange thing happened: In the home folder, I can run `perl -MDevice::SerialPort -e 'print "OK"` fine, but if I copy it to the site_perl folder, I get the "Cannot locate..." error although the files exist with correct permissions.

Comment: Do you want to expand your answer with the infos from my comment? Since you gave me the important information necessary to get it running at least in theory, I would like to give you the correct solution marker. Otherwise, I'll answer my question myself and explain the process to get the module compiled correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I had a copying error which caused the "Cannot find error", so please ignore the second half of my first comment, unfortunately, I cannot edit it anymore. Everything works great now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Go ahead and provide your own answer and accept it.